# CSS background half

Tags: css

I have a background with 2 colors cut in half.
The page has sticky footer.

Is any better way can do this and still keep sticky footer?
I have did some research, but it all affect the sticky footer.

```
* {margin:0;}
html {position: relative; min-height: 100%; background:#F6E038;}

body {margin: 0 0 100px;}/* bottom = footer height */
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%; background:gray;
    }

<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a div between body and your contain. This work pretty well.

```
#red{position:fixed; background:red; width:50%; height:100%; z-index:-1}

<div id="red"></div>
```